# Quantlib python Heston model: generate path, get "Boost assertion failed: px != 0"

Tags: python, montecarlo, quantlib

I'm trying to generate the underlying paths using GaussianPathGenerator with HestonProcess in Quantlib python. But it gives me "RuntimeError: Boost assertion failed: px != 0".

The paths generate fine if I replace the Heston process with a BS or HullWhite process. Does anyone know why the Heston one is not working?

Thanks a lot for help!

import QuantLib as ql

```
today = ql.Date(21, 10, 2020)
daycount = ql.Actual360()
calendar = ql.TARGET()
r_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(today, 0.02, daycount))
d_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(today, 0.01, daycount))
v0, kappa, theta, sigma, rho = 0.03, 10, 0.03, 0.4, 0.3
hs_process = ql.HestonProcess(r_ts, d_ts, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(100)), v0, kappa, theta, sigma, rho)

bs_process = ql.BlackScholesProcess(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(100)), r_ts, 
                                    ql.BlackVolTermStructureHandle(ql.BlackConstantVol(0, calendar, 0.20, daycount)))

timestep = 50
length = 1.0
rng = ql.GaussianRandomSequenceGenerator(ql.UniformRandomSequenceGenerator(timestep, ql.UniformRandomGenerator()))
seq = ql.GaussianPathGenerator(hs_process, length, timestep, rng, False)

path_1 = seq.next()
```

---

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-e8c522a62dd1> in <module>
----> 1 path1 = seq.next()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.py in next(self)
  22328 
  22329     def next(self):
> 22330         return _QuantLib.GaussianPathGenerator_next(self)
  22331 
  22332     def antithetic(self):

RuntimeError: Boost assertion failed: px != 0
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help?

Comment: Yes! It's editted with a minimal working example. Thank you@Léonard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heston process is 2-dimensional (it evolves both the underlying *and* its volatility), so it needs to be passed to a `GaussianMultiPathGenerator`.  Unfortunately the SWIG machinery in the wrappers doesn't catch the type mismatch; it just tries to cast the process to a 1-dimensional one, resulting in a null pointer when the cast fails.

For the same reason, you'll have to initialize the `GaussianRandomSequenceGenerator` with `2*timesteps`, because it has to provide random numbers enough for both variables in the process.

All in all, your code should read:

```
rng = ql.GaussianRandomSequenceGenerator(ql.UniformRandomSequenceGenerator(2*timestep, ql.UniformRandomGenerator()))
times = list(ql.TimeGrid(length, timestep))
seq = ql.GaussianMultiPathGenerator(hs_process, times, rng)
```

Calling `path = seq.next()` will return a `Multipath` instance; `path.value()[0]` will be the path of the underlying, `path.value()[1]` the path of its volatility.

Comment: Thank you Luigi! You not only resolved my question, but also provided a lot of insights into the mechanism behind, which is super helpful to my deeper digging into the C++ version and SWIG wrapping later on. Much appreciated for your help! You are legend.